# In A-Frame/THREE.js, is there a method like the Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint() from Unity?

Tags: three.js, aframe

I know a method from Unity whichs is very useful to convert a screen position to a world position : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html

I've been looking for something similar in A-Frame/THREE.js, but I didn't find anything.

Is there an easy way to convert a screen position to a world position in a plane which is positioned a given distance from the camera ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done using `Raycaster`. An equivalent function using three.js would be written like this:

```
function screenToWorldPoint(screenSpaceCoord, target = new THREE.Vector3()) {

  // convert the screen-space coordinates to normalized device coordinates 
  // (x and y ranging from -1 to 1):

  const ndc = new THREE.Vector2()
  ndc.x = 2 * screenSpaceCoord.x / screenWidth - 1;
  ndc.y = 2 * screenSpaceCoord.y / screenHeight - 1;

  // `Raycaster` can be used to convert this into a ray:

  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  raycaster.setFromCamera(ndc, camera);

  // finally, apply the distance:

  return raycaster.ray.at(screenSpaceCoord.z, target);
}
```

Note that coordinates in browsers are usually measured from the top/left corner with y pointing downwards. In that case, the NDC calculation should be:

```
ndc.y = 1 - 2 * screenSpaceCoord.y / screenHeight;
```

Another note: instead of using a set distance in `screenSpaceCoord.z` you could also let three.js compute an intersection with any Object in your scene. For that you can use `raycaster.intersectObject()` and get a precise depth for the point of intersection with that object. See the documentation and various examples linked here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Raycaster

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I knew I could do this with intersectObject() before, but I didn't want to have to instanciate a plane in the scene just for that. I was missing the `raycaster.ray.at()` method :)

Comment: Actually, what I really needed at the end was `raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, target)`, so I had to create a plane, but not a "real" one.